# C#: Sorting on date field in a Winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

In an sqlite database I have a date field stored as a TEXT property with the following format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

(e.g., the text in the field looks like: 28/04/2009 19:15:17)

I have bound a DataGridView to the database via the GUI in VS2008. So basically all the code was automatically generated for me. When I start my app it reads the database and displays all the rows in the DataGridView. I can sort on all columns except the date column. I suspect this is because the DataGridView thinks the date column is just plain text. How do I get this to work as I want it to?

**UPDATE**

As far as I am aware there is no DATE type in sqlite so I have to store as TEXT. Happy to be told otherwise though.

**UPDATE**
The user would like to see the date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Thank you.

Comment: yes i think this is the case but even it is string you could sort it by clicking header.what type have you used in  db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of implementations of SortableBindingList that you can find on the internet, including one from MSDN.  This blog [example](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/) may help.  You can use known datatypes and and get correct sorting without having to worry so much about date format strings.  The only requirement would be to convert the date string from the db to a datetime in your bound objecttype.

Comment: Thanks. This looks great. Is this how to do #3 in @Fredrik Mörk's answer?

Comment: Yes.  I have used a modified version of SortableBindingList in a number of my apps.  I typically read my database data into objects instead of just datatables.  Then I can just add the objects I want to an instance of the SortableBindingList and bind that to the datagridview.  Also gives better functionality for custom column binding to my objects.

Comment: Just recently solved this exact problem of date sorting with the SortableBindingList.  Converted the date string to a datetime object and exposed that as the bound data and the SBL did all of the rest.  Works well for any object that implements IComparable (I think that's the name)

Answer (score 3):

If you are treating the date as a string and you want it to sort correctly as a string you should change the date format to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`, that would make the date string sortable. Ideally you should be treating the data type as a date of course.

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to still present it to the user as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss as this is what they would prefer?

Comment: Well, I have not worked extensively with the datagrid, but if you can provide a customized sort for the grid then you could present the date in the presentation format and perform your sorting by parsing the dates into DateTime instances using DateTime.ParseExact for example and then do the comparison on the date types.

Comment: Since your database does not support the date data type, you might also consider parsing the dates into a type safe object which represents the date as a DateTime, this would allow you to treat the dates in a type safe manner once they are surfaced in the .NET side.

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of these (in order of preference):

1. Change the database so that it stores the date values as a `Date` type, not a string. This is "the right thing to do", since you will be able to apply sorting on all levels without any problems. It is likely to be more space efficient as well, since date types are typically just a few bytes in size.
2. If you can't change the database design, change the format in which you store the date text into [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`).
3. Create a layer in between the database and the grid where you read the data into a custom object, where the date value is represented by a `DateTime` field. Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse the string from the database into your custom object.

Comment: I would advise doing **#3** no matter whether **#2** was done or not

Comment: I am very new to Winforms programming. Are there any examples of how to go about 3 please? I haven't got a clue where to start.